# Horizontal and vertical alignment in materialize framework

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

How can I center the login box both horizontal and vertical?

Here is my structure:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            <span class="card-title black-text">Sign In</span>
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="firstname" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="firstname" class="active">First Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="lastname" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="lastname" class="active">Last Name</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using `valign-wrapper` and `valign` class but it does not work.

Comment: What css have you tried?

Comment: Have you done a Google search for vertical and horizontal centering CSS? There's a ton of guides on that.

Comment: No, I'm using materialize framework not pure css.

Comment: You can try looking into using `position: absolute;` and offsetting it by 50% of the height and width of the element it's in, it's hard to say if that'd be helpful without knowing what the rest of your code is doing.

Comment: I would most likely add a margin-left: ; or margin-right: ; and a margin-top:; or margin-bottom:; , that way you can move it around. If none of those do anything, you could try position: absolute;, but it can provide more issues doing so.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the proper (materializecss) way to do it and without messy css:

```
<div class="valign-wrapper" style="width:100%;height:100%;position: absolute;">
    <div class="valign" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3">
                 <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                       <span class="card-title black-text">Sign In</span>
                       <form>
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="firstname" type="text" class="validate">
                                <label for="firstname" class="active">First Name</label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="input-field col s12">
                                <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="lastname" type="text" class="validate">
                                <label for="lastname" class="active">Last Name</label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action">
                       <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In">
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'proper' for materialize = create ton of divs with addition of style tags?

Answer (score 9):

Simply use `offset` to align. Offset the card view by half of what's left.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 offset-m3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title black-text">Sign In</span>
          <form>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="firstname" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="firstname" class="active">First Name</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="lastname" type="text" class="validate">
                <label for="lastname" class="active">Last Name</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sign In">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't vertically align as stated. See my answer below.

Comment: This works, but for the vertical alignment, you just need to wrap it in```<main class="valign-wrapper"></main>``` - or something similar depending on page structure.

Answer (score 7):

Try to this solution, I hope it can help you

```
.card {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Also you can try

```
body (or container-div) {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
.col.s12.m6{
    float: none;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Check out this fiddle,     http://fiddle.jshell.net/8vu47fb2/

use margin-top, margin-bottom to align the box at center.

Answer (score 0):

Set text align property of div

```
<div class="input-field col s12" style="text-align:center">

<div class="input-field col s12" style="text-align:center">

 <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="lastname" type="text" class="validate" style="vertical-align:middle">

<input placeholder="Placeholder" id="firstname" type="text" class="validate" style="vertical-align:middle">
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/kuqqdswg/

Comment: In materialize this is the same as `.center-align`

Answer (score 0):

You need to herit full height, starting at `html` and `body` tags.